# PrimeFaces 3.0.M3

Tags: primefaces

I have been using PrimeFaces-2.0 with Tomcat 6.0 and now, I want to migrate to PrimeFaces 3.0 M3. I've added the jar into the classpath and into the /WEB-INF/lib but when I launch the application I have this error message '**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet**' first and when I am in jsf file I can't see any component when I type 'p:(ctrl+space)'. I am using this namespace url 'xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"'. I don't know where the problem is.

Thks

Answer (score 0):

XML namespace url changed to "http://primefaces.org/ui" and the ResourceServlet is not needed anymore, so you usually can just remove it from your web.xml

Answer (score 0):

what u need to do is

```
     <html xmlns ="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
           xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
           xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
           xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
           xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

         Your Coding...
       .....
       </html>
```